# Python/Django plugin for Dreamweaver

Tags: python, django, dreamweaver

Does a plugin exists for Python/Django into Dreamweaver? Just wondering since Dreamweaver is a great web dev tool.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I remember looking for a plugin too, but came across [this](http://www.djangobook.com/en/beta/chapter04/) stumbling block:

> **Designers are assumed to be comfortable with HTML code**. The template system isn’t designed so that templates necessarily are displayed nicely in WYSIWYG editors such as Dreamweaver. That is too severe of a limitation and wouldn’t allow the syntax to be as nice as it is. Django expects template authors are comfortable editing HTML directly.

That being said, I found a [Dreamweaver extension](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&loc=en_us&extid=1557518) whilst having another quick look, so give it a try and let us know how it goes!  From experience, the Eclipse solution offered by Paolo works very nicely, and the [Komodo](http://www.activestate.com/komodo/) [plugins](http://code.google.com/p/django-komodo-kit/wiki/ActiveState) look great, too.  I know you are looking for a graphical editor, but [emacs](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Emacs) does a very nice job ;)

Comment: Being comfortable with HTML code is one thing. Wanting to create CSS stylesheets without a WYSIWYG editor is quite another. Unfortunately, the Dreamweaver extension you mention seems not to be available any more. :-(

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there's no Django-specific IDE plugins out there.

However I use [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) with [PyDev](http://pydev.sourceforge.net/) for my Django/Python needs and it is quite nice.

Comment: It is very nice, it even has code completion for html and css.

Answer (score 2):

[Found one](http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&loc=en_us&extid=1557518) from some guy named Beshr Kayali, but I can't try it myself, since I don't have Dreamweaver.

Answer (score 0):

Beshir Kayali's plugin fails installation for DW CS5 and Extension Manager CS4.
Irony that it asks for DW CS4 or better, else "upgrade" Extension manager to CS3.

I could put some effort in to make this work, yet this is the sole review of the extension:

> I allows you to insert 6 kinds of template tags; if, for, template variable, block, comment, and tags. You press a button and then get a dialog box asking you for some info with maybe a few options. It doesn't actually do too much from what I can tell, definitely skippable.